# Why is $a_{214}$ nonintegral where $a_0 = 1, a_{n+1}=\frac{1 + a_0^5 + \cdots + a_n^5}{n + 1}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Define the sequence $a_n$ by the following.

> $$a_0 = 1,$$
>
> $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1 + a_0^5 + \cdots + a_n^5}{n + 1}$$

$a_{214}$ is nonintegral.
（https://oeis.org/A108394）

Please tell me the proof.

(By computing the sequence modulo 251 it is easy to show that $a_{251}$ is not integral.)

Comment: This is an example of what is sometimes called a Gobel sequence. You may find an answer in http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/28-3/ibstedt.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In general, we can take the recursion $$a_0=1,\qquad a_{n+1}={1+a_0^k+a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k\over n+1}$$ and rewrite it as $$(n+1)a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n^{k-1}+n)$$ Then choose some prime $p$ and start calculating the $a_i\bmod p$, and if $a_{p-1}(a_{p-1}^{k-1}+p-1)$ isn't a multiple of $p$, you win –– $a_p$ isn't an integer.

It seems that this works for $k=2$ with $p=43$, for $k=3$ with $p=89$, and for $k=4$ with $p=97$.

The trouble with $k=5$ is that 214 isn't a prime, so the calculations don't get off the ground.

I wonder whether 214 isn't a typo, and maybe it's supposed to be some prime like 241 or 251. It's probably worth having a look at the Ibstedt paper to which I linked in my comment on the question.

Comment: a_251 is not integral. I calculate the prime for k <= 1000.(http://manchanr6.blogspot.jp/2016/04/160405.html)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This isn't fully correct and contains some imprecise calculations. The core is using modulo 215. To misquote the OP: *"By computing the sequence modulo **215** it is easy to show that **$a_{215}$** is not integral."*

ORIGINAL:

Doing the calculations modulo 215 gives the following:

$$a_0=1$$
$$a_1=\frac{1+1^5}{1}=2$$
$$a_2=\frac{1+1^5+2^5}{2}=17$$
$$a_3=\frac{1+1^5+2^5+17^5}{3}=473297\equiv82\pmod{215}$$
$$a_4\equiv\frac{1+1^5+2^5+17^5+82^5}{4}\equiv42\pmod{215}$$
$$a_5\equiv\frac{1+1^5+2^5+17^5+82^5+42^5}{5}\equiv171\pmod{215}$$
$$a_6\equiv\frac{1+1^5+2^5+17^5+82^5+42^5+171^5}{6}\equiv171\pmod{215}$$
All consecutive terms are 171 module 215 which leads to your conclusion.

Comment: And how do you divide by 5 modulo $215=5\cdot43$?

Comment: As it is the 5th power there will be 5 terms each with a factor of 215 in the expansions of $(82+215k)^5$ and $(42+215k)^5$. Sorry my answer is a bit brief.

Comment: @IanMiller OK, pursuaded. And this also applies to division by $43$. It even works for $25$. But I still see problems at the step where we need to divide by $125$ ...

Comment: Similar arguments should work at other multiples but yeh I probably need to clean up my answer further. Let me think. Maybe modulo 43 would have been better. Then only need to do special cases of divide by 43, 86, etc.

Comment: Finally, why does $a_{214}\equiv 171\pmod{215}$ even imply that $a_{214}$ is not integral?

Comment: Well I've played with this lots and not made significant progress in cleaning it up. I'll leave it here so someone can build upon it.